# Error while installing (entity component) package in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, entity-component-system

Steps Which I followed :

1. Download latest version of unity 2018.2.0f2
2. After installing unity I changed Scripting runtime version 4.x
3. then I tried to install entity package from package manager but I am getting following error:

An error occurred while resolving packages:

> One or more packages could not be added to the local file system:
>       com.unity.burst: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:797:
>
> com.unity.incrementalcompiler: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:797:
>
> com.unity.package-manager-ui: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:797:
>
> com.unity.textmeshpro: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:797:
>
> A re-import of the project may be required to fix the issue or a manual modification of E:/New Unity Project (3)/Packages/manifest.json file.
>
> Assembly has reference to non-existent assembly 'Unity.Burst' (Packages/com.unity.entities/Unity.Transforms/Unity.Transforms.asmdef)

Can somebody help me to resolve this problem? thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably better to ask this over at the Unity3D forums proper

Answer (score 0):

Unity's Entity Component System is still in experimental mode and requires Unity **beta** version to use it. The *Unity 2018.2.0f2* version you are currently using is not a beta version.

Change your instruction for step **#1** and download *Unity 2018.1.0b12* from [here](https://beta.unity3d.com/download/ed1bf90b40e6/public_download.html). Follow the rest of the instruction as they are.

It's also worth noting that the Entity Component System will only work in the Editor at this time. Don't expect it to work in a build for now.

Comment: if I am installing unity 2018.2.0f2 in other system then everything working fine.

Comment: It's currently made to be used with the Unity beta . Just do that and you should be good